# The function $f(z)=|z|^2$ is only differentiable at the origin

Tags: complex-analysis, derivatives, complex-numbers

Show that a complex function $f(z)=|z|^2$ is continuous on all complex plan $\mathbb{C}$, but it is only differentiable at the origin.

I know that a complex function is continuous at $z_0$
$$\Leftrightarrow f(z_0) \space\exists\space\forall z_0 \in \mathbb{C} $$
$$\Leftrightarrow \lim_{z\to z_0}f(z)\space\exists \space\forall z_0 \in \mathbb{C}$$
$$\Leftrightarrow \lim_{z\to z_0}f(z)= f(z_0)$$

And $f(z_0)$ is continous in all complex plan $\Leftrightarrow$ is continuous at all $z_0 \in \mathbb{C}$ but I do not know how to formally demonstrate this, or that the function is differentiable only at the origin.

Comment: $f$ is complex differentiable if and only if the real and imaginary parts satisfy the Cauchy--Riemann equations.

Comment: $f(z_0)\exists\forall z_0\in\mathbb{C}$ is not correct, from a syntactical point of view.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Write $f(z) = x^2+y^2 + i\cdot 0 = u(x,y) + i v(x,y)$, where $u(x,y) = x^2+y^2$ and $v \equiv 0$. The functions $u$ and $v$ are continuous, so is $f$. But Cauchy-Riemann only holds at the origin: $$u_x = v_y, \quad u_y = -v_x \implies 2x = 0, \quad 2y = 0 \implies z = 0,$$ so since $f$ is continuous, $f$ is differentiable only at the origin, and the derivative is zero.

Comment: In general not need to use these limit ideas to prove the continuity then?

Comment: Depends on how far on the theory you already are. To prove that $$f = u + iv \text{ continuous} \iff u \text{ and }v \text{ continuous}$$you'll need the limits, stuff from multivariable (real) calculus.